# Cytoscape.js: "Uncaught Error: An element must have a core reference and parameters set" when attempting to add node to graph

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask, cytoscape.js

I am trying to write a script to use AJAX to send data from my Python/Flask app to Cytoscape.js (both running on same host). I want to be able to have my cytoscape graph poll for updates from `/update_graph`, which is a flask endpoint that returns JSON data describing nodes/edges to add to the graph. I can create individual nodes and add them to the graph, but when I attempt to do so from within a function, it fails with error `"Uncaught Error: An element must have a core reference and parameters set"`.

I initialized cytoscape like this:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: $('#cytoscape_panel'), // container to render in

    elements: $.getJSON('/update_graph'),

    style: [
        { selector: 'node', 
          style: { 'background-color': '#666', 
                   'label': 'data(id)'}},
        { selector: 'edge', 
          style: { 'width': 3,
                   'line-color': '#ccc', 
                   'target-arrow-color': '#ccc', 
                   'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'}}],

    layout: { name: 'grid', rows: 1 }});
```

And then I include it in my HTML like this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="cytoscape_panel" class="grid-item"></div>
  <div id="info_panel" class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/cytoscape.umd.js"></script>
<script src="js/cytoscape_panel.js"></script>
```

The node that I am creating during initialization is there, and correctly displayed, when I load the page. I can manually add a node by doing the following:

```
d = $.getJSON('/update_graph');
cy.add(d['responseJSON'])
cy.fit()
```

... and again, the new node will show up correctly. However when I take this exact same code, and try to place it in a function it does not work:

```
function foo (){
    d = $.getJSON('/update_graph');
    cy.add(d['responseJSON']);
    cy.fit();
}
```

No new node is created, and I get the following error:

```
"cytoscape.umd.js:1192 Uncaught Error: An element must have a core reference and parameters set
    at error (cytoscape.umd.js:1192)
    at new Element (cytoscape.umd.js:1430)
    at Core.add (cytoscape.umd.js:13340)
    at foo (<anonymous>:3:8)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What does this error mean? Is there something that I'm not understanding about Javascript variable scoping rules that makes it where I cannot access the cy object inside of the function like this?

Comment: It seems like you're misunderstanding how async / promises work here.

Comment: Thanks maxkfranz - I'll read more into async/promises. Is there anything specific you think I'm missing that I should read up about?

Comment: The MDN is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong with this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: No, I did not. @maxkfranz mentioned that it might be a problem related to async / promises, but I still haven't figured it out yet. Please let me know if you do figure it out!